# Oracle Trigger: When Prefix NEW with Colon (:)

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_tr.htm) I found the following example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Print_salary_changes
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON Emp_tab
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.Empno > 0)
DECLARE
    sal_diff number;
BEGIN
    sal_diff  := :new.sal  - :old.sal;
    dbms_output.put('Old salary: ' || :old.sal);
    dbms_output.put('  New salary: ' || :new.sal);
    dbms_output.put_line('  Difference ' || sal_diff);
END;
/
```

Within the `WHEN` I write `new` while after `BEGIN` I write `:new`. What is the difference between `new` and `:new`

Comment: Is "double point" a [colon](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html)?

Comment: sry, yes  - wrong translation....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E):

> In the trigger_body of a simple trigger or the tps_body of a compound trigger, a correlation name is a placeholder for a bind variable. Reference the field of a pseudorecord with this syntax:
>
> ```
> :pseudorecord_name.field_name
> ```
>
> In the `WHEN` clause of a conditional trigger, a correlation name is not a placeholder for a bind variable. Therefore, omit the colon in the preceding syntax.

So you do NOT have the colon in this line:

```
WHEN (new.Empno > 0)
```

But you do in the body, e.g.:

```
sal_diff  := :new.sal  - :old.sal;
```

---

Triggers can sometimes cause confusion because they're in two parts; essentially a SQL/DDL part which in your case is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Print_salary_changes
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON Emp_tab
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.Empno > 0)
```

and then the PL/SQL body which in you case start from:

```
DECLARE
```

but in other cases there won't be a declaration section and then it would start from

```
BEGIN
```

When a trigger has a compilation error the line number reported for PLS- errors is counted from the start of the PL/SQL section, not form the `CREATE` - which can be confusing...